# how to move a scrollbar next to a border? (tumblr html)

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, border, tumblr

if there was a blog with a border around it (e.g. 30px each length ~ ref.: themesbyunlure.tumblr.com/post/91567944508/add-border-around-blog) and then, there's a sidebar that should be to the left of that border like in this theme: http://neothm.com/08/2 or this one: http://shythemes.tumblr.com/13a - i was wondering how you can move the scrollbar? is there a script or something like that?

Comment: Please re-read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. SO isn't a site for script requests.

Comment: i dont even know if its a script im looking for :C